# Query multiple entries from registry at once (using reg query)

Tags: powershell, cmd, registry, regedit

I run subsequent reg queries and this takes quite a time:

```
reg query HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes /s /f "foo"
reg query HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes /s /f "bar"
```

Is there any way to search by multiple values at once with `reg query`?

Comment: Please explain exactly what the task is. By that I mean what are `foo` and `bar`? keys, key values, or key data. What do you mean by takes quite a time? Your commands will be outputting multiple lines, are you really wanting the entire output?

Comment: @Compo they're parts of the class names which are registered with COM. Quite a time - long period of time. Yes, I want the entire output.

Comment: Well if you're only checking for strings in the class names, you do not need to recurse and you should be specifying that you're searching in key names. Using `Reg Query HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes /F foo /K` would do that, _(remembering that if `foo` has spaces to enclose it in doublequotes)_. If you actually wanted to return the key data as well, then you could try passing the keys returned in the command above into another `Reg Query` to see if there's a noticeable speed difference, e.g. `For /F Tokens^=* %A In ('Reg Query HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes /F foo /K 2^>NUL')Do @Reg Query "%A" /S 2>NUL`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, unfortunately **`reg query /s /f` accepts only a *single* filter expression**.

The filter expression:<sup>Tip of the hat to [aschipfl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5047996/aschipfl) for his help.</sup>

- is matched against *all* registry entities by default: key names, value names and data.

  - (OR-ed combinations of) options `/k` (keys), `/v` (values) and `/d` (data) can be used to narrow the scope.

    - `/v` can also be used *without* `/f`, in which case it *requires* a value-name search term (e.g., `/v foo`) that is matched *in full* (see below); `/ve` returns only default values (the values whose name is the empty string) *if they contain data*.
    - **When *combining* `/f` with `/v <valueNameSearchTerm>` or `/ve`**, only combining *key* search (`/k`) via `/f` is supported to narrow down the matches; that is, **the only combinations that make sense are**:

      - `/f <keySearchTerm> /k /v <valueNameSearchTerm>`
      - `/f <keySearchTerm> /k /ve`
      - That way, the `/v <valueNameSearchTerm>` / `/ve` matching is limited to those keys that match `/f <keySearchTerm>`, amounting to AND logic.
      - Any other combination - omitting `/k`, adding `/d`, using just `/d` - effectively causes the `/f` search term to be *ignored*.
  - `/t REG_*` can be used to narrow matching to specified value types, such as `REG_SZ`
- performs case-insensitive *substring* matching by default.

  - supports wildcard characters `*` (any number of chars., including none) and `?` (exactly 1 char.) - though note that something like `foo*` still only performs *substring* matching; there is seemingly no way to *anchor* substrings.

    - As stated, when you use `/v` directly with a value-name search term (e.g., `/v foo`, it must match *in full*; e.g., to find a value name that contains substring `foo`, you then must use `*foo*`.
  - `/e` performs whole-string matching, without wildcard support.
  - `/c` uses case-*sensitive* matching.
- *numeric* data such as `REG_DWORD` is matched in its *decimal* string representation
- *binary* data (`REG_BINARY`) is matched as a "byte string": a list of 2-hex-digit byte values without separators.

Run `reg query /?` to see all options or consult the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/reg-query).

---

**You can use the following PowerShell command to provide *multiple* filters:**

Note:

- The command is **limited to the following search logic** - though it could be adapted to support all `reg query` options, at which point creating a *function wrapper* would definitely be called for:

  - A *regular expression* (with `-match`) rather than wildcard matching (with `-like`) is used, which both simplifies the command and makes it more flexible (it wouldn't be hard to adapt the solution to use wildcard matching instead).
  - **Only registry *data* is searched**, not also key names and value names.

    - For instance, to search *key names only*, the command would be as simple as:
      `Get-ChildItem HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes -Recurse |
      Where-Object { $_.PSChildName -match 'foo|bar' }`
  - Unlike with `reg.exe`, binary data is matched byte by byte, based on their *decimal* string representation.
  - Only the *sub*-keys of the target key are examined, not the target key itself.
- **With a single filter, the command is *slower* than `reg.exe`**, but with *multiple* filters it is eventually likely faster than multiple `reg.exe` calls; for the OP it took 4-5 - YMMV.

  - Replacing the `Get-ChildItem` call with direct use of the .NET framework for recursive key enumeration will likely bring speed improvements, though I have no sense of how much. A purpose-built native binary such as `reg.exe` will always be faster than custom PowerShell code.
  - Generally, the **main advantages of a PowerShell solution** are:

    - *Objects* are being returned, which greatly facilitates subsequent processing (no need for parsing *text* output).
    - The use of regular expressions allows for more sophisticated matching.

```bsh
# The two filters to use, combined into a single regex.
$regex = 'foo|bar'

Get-ChildItem HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes -Recurse | ForEach-Object { 
  foreach ($value in $_.GetValueNames()) { 
    if (($data = $_.GetValue($value)) -match $regex) { 
      [PSCustomObject]@{
        Key = $_.Name
        Value = if ($value) { $value } else { '(default)' }
        Data = $data
      }
    } 
  } 
}
```

The output is something like the following, with the `Data` column containing the matches (scroll to the right; alternatively, pipe the above to `Format-List` for a one-property-per-line view):

```
Key                                                                                             Value     Data
---                                                                                             -----     ----
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\AllSyncRootObjects                                          StatusBar prop:~System.StatusBarViewItemCount;~System.StatusBarSelectedItemCount...
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{0002E132-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}\InprocServer32 Class     Microsoft.Vbe.Interop.CommandBarEventsClass
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{0002E132-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}\InprocServe... Class     Microsoft.Vbe.Interop.CommandBarEventsClass
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{0006F054-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}                (default) Microsoft Outlook InfoBar Control
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{0006F054-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}\InprocServer32 Class     Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlkInfoBarClass
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{0006F054-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}\InprocServe... Class     Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlkInfoBarClass
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{0006F054-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}\ProgID         (default) Outlook.OlkInfoBar.1
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{0006F054-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}\VersionInde... (default) Outlook.OlkInfoBar
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{056440FD-8568-48e7-A632-72157243B55B}                (default) Explorer Navigation Bar
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{05d7b0f4-2121-4eff-bf6b-ed3f69b894d7}                (default) Taskbar Control Panel
...
```